# Animate mesh size change

Tags: mesh

I have this cylinder which I want to get longer (z size) over a certain 50 frames. However, when its size is say 20 at frame 1, then I create a keyframe at frame 50 and change its size to 20, then its size at frame 1 changes to 50 to. How can I get it to animate going from frame 1 to 50, getting longer? Thanks in advance.

I can't upload pictures, so here's a drawing of what I want:

frame 1:

|
|
|

frame 25

|
|
|
|
|

frame 50

|
|
|
|
|
|
|

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a size keyframe on Frame 1 at size 20. Then when you move to Frame 50, scale it up and add a new keyframe, you'll get the scaling animation working correctly.

In addition, if you want the scaling effect to be more even you can also switch into the Graph Editor and change the keyframe interpolation from Bezier to Linear.

Comment: Is a size keyframe any different than a normal one? Because when I try to change the size, no keyframes are made.

Comment: With the object selected you press the I key and then select Scale to set a scaling keyframe. You need to do this on the first and last frame to get the scale to change over time.

Comment: I can't delete keyframes... can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just keyframe the scale on those said frames.  Make sure you're in object mode, hit 'I' when your cursor is in the viewport, click on 'Scaling' as an option.  Scrub to the next position on the timeline, go to the viewport again, hit 's' and then 'z' to scale it to what you want.  Hit I and 'Scaling' again.  Repeat.